# Adding basic pagination to multiple step form

Tags: jquery, forms, each

I am creating a multiple setep form using jQuery. Currently the functionality is limited - the next button will rpgoress the user to the next set successfully. I am tryign to implement some sort of pagination where it will show the user what page they are currently on and what other pages are left.

You can see a fully commented jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QmbNw/6/

Ideally, I would like the list item of the current page to have a class of active, so I can style it differently. The section of the form that is currently showing has a class of selected. I need to figure out a way to add a class of active to each list item with a matching index to that of the selected form pane. See the jsfiddle and it will make sense.

Also, these list items should link to the section so they are clickable.

UPDATE:

I added the following jQuery in, hoping it would add an active state to the current list item:

```
if($(this).hasClass("visible")){
     $(this).parent().find("li:nth-child(" + pageNum+ ")").addClass("active");
}
```

See jsfiddle for context: http://jsfiddle.net/QmbNw/6/

Comment: So then, what is your question?

Comment: How to add the active states to the list items based on what part of the form is being shown (class selected) - essentially adding pagination

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this pretty easily by:

- Creating a variable called currentPage
- Creating a function to hide/show the pagination "tabs" based on the currentPage
- Created IDs and classes to help the jquery drive page actions

Updated ex here:  http://jsfiddle.net/QmbNw/5/

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I was looking to have 3 persistent list items, and one would have an active state at any given time, so they are visually differentiable.

Comment: And I want this to work dynamically, so I do not have to give the articles an ID (so I can have as many articles as need be)

Comment: I added the following jquery hoping this would add the classes that I need, but it doesnt:  if($(this).hasClass("visible")){
          $(this).parent().find("li:nth-child(" + pageNum+ ")").addClass("active");
         }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) - you got one great with jQuery-UI.

In order to serialize your datas, look at the [Mike Alsup](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) jquery form plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using an additional index. Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Azxjt/